# Pulling Single File from 20GB folder/7zip Archive on Mac

Tags: mac, 7-zip, archiving

I have a large folder (~20GB) containing a rather large amount of old archived files (~400K). I only need one though. What would be the easiest way, if possible, to only extract the file I need rather than sitting forever and a day for all of the files to load (if that's even possible)? Right now the folder is sitting on my external hard drive. I also have the original 7zip archive - not sure if that would be easier to extract from.

Answer (score 3):

Use p7zip from terminal:

```
7z e archive.7z-o output  -r
```

You can install p7zip with `brew install p7zip`.

You can install homebrew with:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that there are many, many ways that you can do this, but I know that [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) allows you to extract individual files from an archive because I use the feature all the time. That would save you having to extract all of the other files extraneously.

EDIT: After re-reading this and realizing that you want this to be done on Mac, you can see [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory) on unix.stackechange for how to do what you want easily in command line

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!